# Loop through multiple ul list

Tags: jquery, loops

I have multiple `<ul>` list with the same number of `<li>` elements:

```
<ul id='first'>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul id='second'>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>

<ul id='third'>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

I want to first get the first `<li>` element of each  `<ul>` (1,5,9), then the second for each (2,6,10) and so on.

I know that I can get the all `<li>` elements of a `<ul>` by `$('#first li').each(...)`. Is there a similar command to get the `<li>`  elements in the above described order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **[`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** (or **[`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)**) method along with **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** method.

```
// iterate ove li elements
$('#first li').each(function(i) {
  console.log(
    // get text from li
    $(this).text(),
    // get li from second based on index and get text
    $('#second li').eq(i).text(), //  you can also use `$('#second li:eq(' + i + ')')`
    // get li from third based on index and get text
    $('#third li').eq(i).text());
});
```

```js
// iterate ove li elements
$('#first li').each(function(i) {
  console.log(
    // get text from li
    $(this).text(),
    // get li from second based on index and get text
    $('#second li').eq(i).text(),
    // get li from third based on index and get text
    $('#third li').eq(i).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='first'>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul id='second'>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>

<ul id='third'>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

---

Or you can use **[`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/)** method with callback instead of **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** method.

```
// iterate over li elements where first argument holds index
// and second argument holds the text content
$('#first li').text(function(i, v) {
  console.log(
    v,
    // get li from second based on index and get text
    $('#second li').eq(i).text(),
    // get li from third based on index and get text
    $('#third li').eq(i).text());
});
```

```js
// iterate ove li elements
$('#first li').text(function(i, text) {
  console.log(
    text,
    // get li from second based on index and get text
    $('#second li').eq(i).text(),
    // get li from third based on index and get text
    $('#third li').eq(i).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='first'>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul id='second'>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>

<ul id='third'>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This will not work if any `ul` later have more than 4 `li`

Comment: @Rajesh :  I just added answer for the question ...... ___I have multiple <ul> list with the same number of <li> elements:___

Comment: Just a question. Will `li:eq(2)` be not better than `.find('li').eq(2)`? I mean second approach will fetch all `li`s and then filter out 2nd element.

Comment: @Rajesh :  `:eq()` is a jQuery pseudo-class selector.... not a css selector.... it defined within the jQuery library.... so I think both are working internally as same :) not sure...... for more need to look into the library

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use `:eq` to find necessary element in list

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var uls = $("ul");
  
  // Get length of lis in all uls
  var lengths = $.map(uls, function(ul){
    return $(ul).find('li').length;
  });
  
  // Get max length to iterateover it.
  var maxLen = Math.max.apply(null, lengths);
  
  // Loop over maxLen and get li's value
  for (var i=0; i<maxLen; i++){
    var lis = $.map(uls.find('li:eq('+i+')'), function(li){
      return $(li).text()
    });
    console.log(lis)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='first'>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul id='second'>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>

<ul id='third'>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi . can you explain why not each loop or advantage of using map over each. Just asking

Comment: Both are fine. Actually your approach for calculating max length is better, but I did this just in case we need all lengths.

Comment: @YoYo Thanks. Also for your reference, check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/bc401539/). Not related to this question, but just a comparison between `Math.max.apply` vs `for`

Answer (score 1):

Get the count of max li children then iterate accordingly

```
var count=0;

$("ul").each(function(){

   var num = $(this).children("li").length;
   if(num > count)
   {
     count = num;
   }

});



for (var i=1 ; i<=count ; i++)
{

  $("ul").each(function(){


    alert($(this).children().eq(i).text());

  });
}
```

[**Working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6ryg2b5f/3/)

Comment: This will only give first li. please read OP's requirement. Also `$('ul').find('li:first')` will do the trick. No need for `$.each`

Comment: @Rajesh :  Oh yes I did not notice that thanks. Corrected the code

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#first, #second, #third').find('li');
```

Will do the trick

jQuery might have `.child()` method for immediate child, I don't remember know.

More verbal would be:

```
$('#full .first .selector, #second .full .selector, .etc');
```

As jQuery takes CSS selectors in all amounts but that might be less and less legible as number of selectors grow but you can always builds it first.